# Can spike protein induced cell fusion be triggered by the mRNA vaccine?

Tags: cell-biology, coronavirus, vaccination, mrna, covid

The mRNA-based vaccines cannot lead to COVID-19 or its symptoms since they only lead to the production of the spike protein in the cell.

However, the spike protein itself can lead to cell fusion:
[Quantitative assays reveal cell fusion at minimal levels of SARS-CoV-2 spike protein and fusion from without](https://www.cell.com/iscience/fulltext/S2589-0042(21)00138-3?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS2589004221001383%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)

Is this a potential risk of the mRNA vaccine ?
I could imagine, that the spike protein needs to be bound to the virus to induce this effect ?
I could not find any literature where the effect of the unbound spike protein is tested.

Comment: Why the down vote ?

Comment: The virus membrane anchored spike provokes virion-cell fusion, the cell membrane anchored spike provokes cell-cell fusion, when encountering ACE2. In most vaccines the 2P mutation greatly reduces this behavior (not in the AstraZeneca vaccine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mRNA vaccines encode a mutant version of the spike protein in which the structural transition needed to to fuse membranes is blocked. This was done to make the immune response focus on the pre-fusion state, which is much better for neutralizing the virus.

From https://cen.acs.org/pharmaceuticals/vaccines/tiny-tweak-behind-COVID-19/98/i38:

> Fortuitously, Graham and a former postdoc, Jason McLellan, devised a solution to this problem before the pandemic. Through a bit of structural biology and persistent protein engineering, McLellan discovered that adding two prolines—the most rigid of the 20 amino acids—to a key joint of a vaccine’s spike protein could stabilize the structure’s prefusion shape. This 2P mutation worked in preclinical studies of Graham and Moderna’s MERS vaccine, so they applied it to Moderna’s COVID-19 vaccine.

I don't know if cells expressing wild-type spike protein would fuse into syncytia, but it seems very unlikely to happen with the vaccine spike.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123798/discussion-on-answer-by-timeskull-can-spike-protein-induced-cell-fusion-be-trigg).